# Web Scraping Specific Data from OpenWeather (One Call) API into CSV file

Tags: web-scraping, beautifulsoup

So, as above I have a problem on scraping from the openweather api. I have done some practice with scraping with bs4, but the format from the openweather api is a totally  different thing hahah.
FYI, I've only learnt this around only a week since it's a requirement (project) from school. (Prof hasn't taught us anything and only gave reading materials, so yeah...)

So far this is the code:

```
#import libs
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs
from urllib.request import urlopen

#Takes the url
url = "https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/onecall?lat=14.590456&lon=120.9774225&units=metric&appid=<API Key>"

#Website Actions
url = urlopen(url)
urlRead = url.read()
url.close()

#BS Actions
# parses html into a soup data structure to traverse html as if it were a json data type.
html = bs(urlRead, "html.parser")
html
```

This was when i tried to see what stuff I can get from it, which resulted to: (Without the spacing, I just used jsbeautifier for that)

```
{

    "lat":14.59,
    "lon":120.98,
    "timezone":"Asia/Manila",
    "current": {

        "dt":1587533672,
        "sunrise":1587505076,
        "sunset":1587550252,
        "temp":34.62,
        "feels_like":36.42,
        "pressure":1010,
        "humidity":56,
        "dew_point":24.55,
        "uvi":13.13,
        "clouds":20,
        "visibility":10000,
        ...
        ],
        "clouds":11,
        "uvi":13.74
    }

]
```

}

So the problem is, how to I extract only specific data (into a csv) from this since the whole thing is a single text?

Something like, only the data from current:{}, or certain hours from hourly:{}, etc.

Answer (score 0):

Do some reading on json structures and converting dictionaries to dataframe. It's as simple as iterating through your list, and calling the `key` in your json response.

Secondly, I'd use `requests` here and just read in the json response to store as list/dictionaries.

```
import requests
import pandas as pd


#Takes the url
url = "https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/onecall?lat=14.590456&lon=120.9774225&units=metric&appid=<API Key>"

#Website Actions
jsonData = requests.get(url).json()
```

Call the `key` `'current'`:

```
jsonData = {

    "lat":14.59,
    "lon":120.98,
    "timezone":"Asia/Manila",
    "current": {

        "dt":1587533672,
        "sunrise":1587505076,
        "sunset":1587550252,
        "temp":34.62,
        "feels_like":36.42,
        "pressure":1010,
        "humidity":56,
        "dew_point":24.55,
        "uvi":13.13,
        "clouds":20,
        "visibility":10000,
        "clouds":11,
        "uvi":13.74
    }
}


df = pd.DataFrame(jsonData['current'],index=[0])
```

**Output:**

```
print(df.to_string())
           dt     sunrise      sunset   temp  feels_like  pressure  humidity  dew_point    uvi  clouds  visibility
0  1587533672  1587505076  1587550252  34.62       36.42      1010        56      24.55  13.74      11       10000
```